# Changing windows form size

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VB 2010 to create a program that can access information stored in an Access database. Whenever I populate a list box to show the content of a database via data binding, it causes the form window and controls to resize themselves when run. It then alters the size of all other forms and controls opened while the program is running.

I am unsure as to how to stop it from doing this. When I remove the data binding, the form size reverts back to how it should be. How do I correct this? The code I'm using to do this is as follows. Is it the listbox or the code that's causing this unwanted resizing?

```
Private Sub C172_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'C172DataSet.C172' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

Me.C172TableAdapter.Fill(Me.C172DataSet.C172)
```

Comment: Show your code, preferably in the form of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Im new to this website and i dont know how to post code in a better format Private Sub C172_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      
        Me.C172TableAdapter.Fill(Me.C172DataSet.C172)

Comment: No, by editing the question. Please read the help files!

Comment: i will get on that! Thanks for your patience

Comment: Note that I won't be answering this myself; I know nothing of VB 2010. I was assigned to assess this question as a review task.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the direction though!